# Executing Interactive SSH Command via Python script

Tags: python

```
I am trying to automate to collect the logs from the Cisco Call Manager via CLI by using the from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction where I am not able to send the interactive command to the server. 

While trying to download the logs, it will ask information like SFTP IP address, username, password and directory which needs to send an interactive command.
```

whenever the code runs, it stops at the interactive command section where its not sending the command to the server because of which python script stops here. need to know is there any other way to code these requirements.

```
for example

Below section is interactive shell where I have to type y/xx.xx.xx.xx/22/User ID/Password/Directory but I can't do the same. 

I need help here.. to send the command 

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Would you like to proceed [y/n]? y
SFTP server IP: xx.xx.xx.xx
SFTP server port [22]: 22
User ID: *****
Password: *****
Download directory: /
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Command Line Interface is starting up, please wait ...

   Welcome to the Platform Command Line Interface

VMware Installation:
    4 vCPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8180 CPU @ 2.50GHz
    Disk 1: 110GB, Partitions aligned
    6144 Mbytes RAM

admin:file get activelog /syslog/AlternateSyslog
Please wait while the system is gathering files info ...
 Get file: active/syslog/AlternateSyslog
done.
Sub-directories were not traversed.
Number of files affected: 5
Total size in Bytes: 23354752
Total size in Kbytes: 22807.375
Would you like to proceed [y/n]? y
SFTP server IP: xx.xx.xx.xx
SFTP server port [22]: 
User ID: *****
Password: *****
Download directory: /

The authenticity of host 'xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx)' can't be established.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
.....
Transfer completed.
admin:


I am able to get the show command output but not able to download the logs.



    #!/usr/bin/python
    # PSFL license
    # Importing SSHClientInteraction from paramiko 
    import paramiko
    from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction
    import threading
    # Specify connection info for each node in square brackets: ["IP ADDRESS", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"]
    connection = [["xx.xx.xx.xx", "userid", "password"]]

    # Define function which is responsible for opening SSH connection and running specified commands
    def cucm(ip, username, password):
        sshsession = paramiko.SSHClient()
        sshsession.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        sshsession.connect(ip, username=username, password=password)
         # "display=True" is just to show you what script does in real time. While in production you can set it to False
        interact = SSHClientInteraction(ssh, timeout=600, display=True)
        # program will wait till session is established and CUCM returns admin prompt
        interact.expect('admin:') 
        # program runs show status command
        interact.send('show status')
        # program waits for show status command to finish (this happen when CUCM returns admin prompt) 
        interact.except('admin:') 
        # program sends syslog to download the file
        interact.send('file get activelog /syslog/AlternateSyslog')
        if interact.last_match == 'Would you like to proceed [y/n]? ': # program matches prompted command by using if command and will send interact command to it. 
            interact.send('y')
        if interact.last_match == 'SFTP server IP:':
            interact.send('xx.xx.xx.xx')
        if interact.last_match == 'SFTP server port [22]:':
            interact.send('22')
        if interact.last_match == 'User ID:':
            interact.send('userid')
        if interact.last_match == 'Password:':
            interact.send('password')
        if interact.last_match == 'Download directory:':
            interact.send('/')
        interact.expect('admin:')
        output = interact.current_output_clean # program saves output of show status command to the "output" variable
        sshsession.close()

    # Run loop which will open separate thread for each node specified in the connection list. This targets "session" function defined at the beginning 
    for i in connection:
        t = threading.Thread(target = cucm, args = (i[0], i[1], i[2]))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Below is the output for the python script.

```
there is no error message but it stops at Would you like to proceed [y/n]?  here

Command Line Interface is starting up, please wait ...

   Welcome to the Platform Command Line Interface

VMware Installation:
    4 vCPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8180 CPU @ 2.50GHz
    Disk 1: 110GB, Partitions aligned
    6144 Mbytes RAM

admin:file get activelog /syslog/AlternateSyslog
Please wait while the system is gathering files info ...
 Get file: active/syslog/AlternateSyslog
done.
Sub-directories were not traversed.
Number of files affected: 1
Total size in Bytes: 2261400
Total size in Kbytes: 2208.3984
Would you like to proceed [y/n]?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the global configuration command "file prompt quiet" at the beginning of your program before any other commands are sent.  This will suppress any yes/no questions and auto them to the default.  Just make sure that at the end of the code you turn it back off to prevent any later nasty surprises using "file prompt alert".

This works in most Cisco IOS platforms, if the command is different in CUCM I'm sure there will be an equivalent to do the same thing.

Comment: hi dave, thanks for the reply. i checked the command for CUCM but unfortunately, there is no command like that

Comment: That is unfortunate, I'm away at the mo but when I get back to work I'll ask our Collaboration CCIE and see if he has any ideas. Just out of curiosity have you tried just sending a new line to the console? "/n" not sure if that will hit enter for you if the default is acceptable, or even "yes/n" to type the command? 2 minutes to try it so worth a go.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you already sorted this out, but I see, that you have there one small type, which could stop that script of moving forward:
you have there:
interact.**except**('admin:')
instead of:
interact.**expect**('admin:')